# {% if session['username'] =='' %} doesn't display the login button

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I want to display the login button if the username is empty.

But it doesn't display the login button instead the part within the else statement is rendered but the username is blank. I tried with double quotes as well and it is the same. Can anyone see what is wrong?

```
   {% if session['username'] =='' %}
<button>


          <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="sendTokenToServer();">
<a href='javascript:sendTokenToServer()'>Login with Facebook</a>

</fb:login-button>


        </button>
<!--END FACEBOOK SIGN IN -->

{% endif %}
{% else %}
<a href="{{url_for('fbdisconnect')}}">Welcome {{session['username']}} <br>Logout</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: `{% if not session['username'] %}` ?

Comment: You could render `session['username']` in your template to see what the value is. My guess would be that it is `None` which does not equal `''`.

Comment: {% if not session['username'] %} also doesn't display the login button. I also tried {% if session['username']==None %} and that also doesn't display the login button.

Comment: Nothing is printed out with session['username'] It just appears blank when I print it out as in Welcome {{session['username']}}

Comment: You need to find out what data type `session['username']` is. Try printing it out the console, if you can't do that, put your app in debug mode, force it to error after rendering the template and use the werkzeug console to find out. Or render the `type` in the template.

Comment: How do I render the type in the template?

Comment: try output the true value with: `{{ repr(session['username']) }}` @John

Comment: That doesn't work as repr is undefined. But thanks for the suggestion. I got it working using the below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
 {% if 'username' not in session %}
```

Comment: Thanks. This did it.